# AWS elastic beanstalk - Failed to Launch Environment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I follow this [Deploying an Express application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html) and get stuck in "Create an Elastic Beanstalk environment" step 2:

When I run `~/node-express$ eb create --sample node-express-env`, it got error and suggest me to check log. So I go to console and look at the environment creation log. There is error of fail to create load balancer. Looks like this:

`Creating load balancer failed Reason: At least two subnets in two different Availability Zones must be specified (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: f4be9cd2-469e-4b44-a82f-d4f6dc2bb69a; Proxy: null)`

I also tried to create the environment by console. No personal code, just the "sample application" from AWS. I tried both `node.js` and `Python`, all the same.

Got same error. Here is the whole log:

`2020-09-08 19:29:45 UTC+1000     INFO Launched environment: Tutorials-env. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.`

`2020-09-08 19:29:43 UTC+1000    ERROR Creating security group named: awseb-e-m2hqmqrmb6-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-93PRN501BC96 failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled`

`2020-09-08 19:29:43 UTC+1000    ERROR Stack named 'awseb-e-m2hqmqrmb6-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBV2LoadBalancer, AWSEBSecurityGroup].`

`2020-09-08 19:29:27 UTC+1000    ERROR Creating load balancer failed Reason: At least two subnets in two different Availability Zones must be specified (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: cf359cab-39bd-4dec-aaf4-e21271a97823; Proxy: null)`

`2020-09-08 19:29:27 UTC+1000    INFO Created security group named: sg-01ed408338797a1ef`

Thanks guys.

---

More info:
Permission should be enough. I switched to root account but still got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At least two subnets in two different Availability Zones must be specified

As the error message suggests, you need to specify **two AZs** for Application Load Balancer.

You can customize the subnets for your ALB using `ELBSubnets` option in [aws:ec2:vpc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-ec2vpc).

Comment: Hi Marcin. Thanks for you answer. I just created a new account and launch an `eb` environment, everything is smooth. So I guess I must have done something wrong to my VPC or ELB setting. How come the previous config can mess up this new environment launching (even with the default template).

Comment: @JasonZheng EB has concept of saved configurations. Thus maybe they got reused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check default subnets. Cloudformation code in Beanstalk needs tries to find them. May be you recreated default VPC and subnets so they are not DEFAULT.
here is an AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-subnet
I had same issue and fixes it with new default vpc and subnets.

Answer (score -1):

@JasonZheng -- Piggybacking on @Marcin's comment, the issue may well be with other resources (outside of beanstalk) in your account. Try same thing(s) in different region -- see if the same issues arises. That may be of some diagnostic help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).